# mongo aggregate group with inner group/count on array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am stuck and confused with my current Aggregate expression and I was hoping on some input or a solution in Mongo itself.

The original data from Mongo (simplified to only the fields I need right now):

```
[{
  'status': 'Cancelled',
  'CIC Package': 'Test Gallery Cafe',
},
{
  'status': 'Completed',
  'CIC Package': 'Design Thinking workshop'
},
{
  'status': 'Tentative',
  'CIC Package': 'Design Thinking workshop'
},
{
  'status': 'Confirmed',
  'CIC Package': 'Product / solution demonstration'
},

....etc
]
```

In general...there are 1000s of records of probably 8 'CIC packages' with different  statuses (Confirmed, Cancelled, Tentative, Completed) and other data that I have excluded for now.

The end result I am looking for is something like this:

```
    [{
    "_id" : "Test Gallery Café",
    "package" : "Test Gallery Café",
    "status" : [
      {
        "Cancelled": 1
      },
      {
        "Completed": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : "Design Thinking workshop",
    "package" : "Design Thinking workshop",
    "status" : [
      {
        "Cancelled": 3
      },
      {
        "Completed": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : "Product / solution demonstration",
    "package" : "Product / solution demonstration",
    "status" : [
      {

        "Completed": 10
      },
      {
        "Cancelled": 3
      },
      {
        "Confirmed": 1
      }
    ]
  }]
```

So per `CIC package` which I renamed to `package` in the `$group` I want to have a count of each status that exists in the dataset. The statuses and packages are not under my control so in time new ones could be added. It needs to be a dynamic group.

I came as far as this:

```
  db.reportData.aggregate([
  {
    $project: 
    {
      'CIC package': 1,
      'Status': 1
    }
   }
 , 
   {
     $group: 
     {
       _id: '$CIC package',
       package: 
       {
         $first: '$CIC package'
       }
     ,
       status:
       {
         $push: '$Status'
       }
     }
   }
 ]).toArray()
```

which resulted in something likes this:

```
  [{
    "_id" : "Test Gallery Café",
    "package" : "Test Gallery Café",
    "status" : [
      "Cancelled",
      "Completed"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : "Design Thinking workshop",
    "package" : "Design Thinking workshop",
    "status" : [
      "Cancelled",
      "Cancelled",
      "Cancelled",
      "Completed",
      "Completed"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : "Product / solution demonstration",
    "package" : "Product / solution demonstration",
    "status" : [
      "Completed",
      "Completed",
      "Cancelled",
      "Processing",
      "Cancelled",
      "Cancelled",
      "Completed",
      "Completed",
      "Completed",
      "Completed",
      "Completed",
      "Completed",
      "Completed",
      "Completed",
      "Completed",
      "Tentative"
    ]
  }]
```

This is a small extraction of a much larger set, but it a good sample of the result so far.

I have tried `unwind` after the last `group` which does create new records that I possibly could `group` again, but I am getting a bit confused right now. And maybe I am doing it inefficiently.
I think I am almost there but I would love some input.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your aggregation pipeline makes reference to several fields not present in your data sample. Please show your real data and the intended result.

Comment: The real data is private, but I think I did show the data under original table.
The only fields that matter are 'SIS package' and 'Status'. The main problem I have is the top dataset in my post, it shows all the statuses per package, but I need to have a count of each status per package. It is a pretty complex thing to write up. Don't know how to make it more clear.

Comment: You could make it more clear by referring to fields like "package" which is present in your data and not "SIS package" or the other way around. Notably you make reference to "Start Date" which has no equivalent at all. If you abstract too much in what you ask, then you run the risk that the answer does not fit your data purposes. Or we run the risk of a lot of communication with you because you do not understand. Please clear that up so you are actually asking for what you need.

Comment: I transform 'CIC package' to 'package in the first `$group`. Start Date is not used, I will remove that. I just wanted to show that the original data is a bigger object but none of this fields matter for query/question.
I will do my best to clear it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically seem to want the "count of status" for each type, which is a matter of grouping first to count those and then just by the primary `_id` of the object:

```js
db.reportData.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$status" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "package": "$package",
            "status": "$status"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "package": { "$first": "$_id.package" },
        "status": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$_id.status", "Completed" ] },
                    { "Completed": "$count" },
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$_id.status", "Cancelled" ] },
                        { "Cancelled": "$count" },
                        { "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$_id.status", "Processing" ] },
                            { "Processing": "$count" },
                            { "Tentative": "$count" }
                        ]}
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Or just keep it generic with a "type" field for each status in the results:

```js
db.reportData.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$status" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "package": "$package",
            "status": "$status"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "package": { "$first": "$_id.package" },
        "status": {
            "$push": {
                "type": "$_id.status",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Which will give you results like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : "Test Gallery Café",
        "package" : "Test Gallery Café",
        "status" : [
                {
                        "type" : "Completed",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "type" : "Cancelled",
                        "count" : 1
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "Design Thinking workshop",
        "package" : "Design Thinking workshop",
        "status" : [
                {
                        "type" : "Completed",
                        "count" : 2
                },
                {
                        "type" : "Cancelled",
                        "count" : 3
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "Not specified",
        "package" : "Not specified",
        "status" : [
                {
                        "type" : "Processing",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "type" : "Tentative",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "type" : "Cancelled",
                        "count" : 3
                },
                {
                        "type" : "Completed",
                        "count" : 11
                }
        ]
}
```

---

This gets a bit better in future releases of MongoDB with `$filter`:

```js
db.reportData.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "package": 1,
        "statusComplete": {
            "$size": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$status",
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [ "$$el", "Completed" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "statusCancelled": {
            "$size": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$status",
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [ "$$el", "Cancelled" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

As it is basically about "counting the matched elements in the arrays", and the last could be expanded upon to actually produce the same array result as the former, with a lot less overhead due to no `$unwind`. But of course that is yet to be released, but it's just a sample of what you will be able to do in the future.

Also for the record, the data presented in the original post before alteration was this:

```js
{
        "_id" : "Test Gallery Café",
        "package" : "Test Gallery Café",
        "status" : [
                "Cancelled",
                "Completed"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "Design Thinking workshop",
        "package" : "Design Thinking workshop",
        "status" : [
                "Cancelled",
                "Cancelled",
                "Cancelled",
                "Completed",
                "Completed"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "Not specified",
        "package" : "Not specified",
        "status" : [
                "Completed",
                "Completed",
                "Cancelled",
                "Processing",
                "Cancelled",
                "Cancelled",
                "Completed",
                "Completed",
                "Completed",
                "Completed",
                "Completed",
                "Completed",
                "Completed",
                "Completed",
                "Completed",
                "Tentative"
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Maybe it is a bit more clear now that I amended my question, but I would like not to hardcode the statuses  because I have no control over them. Currently there are 6 of them but that could change in the future. The package's to, they could add new packages to their system. I have implemented the first part of your $group which does create the statuses per package as separate rows and now I need to group it back to packages with a array of all its statuses and their respective counts. :) sigh

Comment: @Mattijs I think your "edit" has made things even more obscure than the question was to begin with. At least that showed a source that could come to your expected result ( as the code here does ), but now it is completely unclear how to get there.

Comment: You are kidding... Well I disagree. I just want to get to the end result as displayed in the second code block. I am almost there with part of your solution, only I can't do the $cond part because the statuses have to be counted dynamically. I am just figuring out how to do second and last $group to get the end result I want: per package a an array object status objects with the counts. In MYSQL I would have no trouble doing this but in mongo I get utterly confused. Maybe I should call it a day. Tomorrow might bring new insight

Comment: @Mattijs Might be a good idea as you seem a bit frazzled. MongoDB cannot "dynamically" assign keys to documents with the aggregation framework. Perhaps a generic "type" field would be more appropriate for your end results. Otherwise you need to specify each possible type in the conditional format as demonstrated.

Comment: I have a working version, I will post it as an answer right now. Please hang on :)

Comment: @Mattijs perhaps you should read all of the content ( and alternative ) above before posting that you came to your own solution.

Comment: I think that was a matter of us posting at the same time. I didn't see your update when I was posting a possible answer. I will now look at yours because I am convinced you more experienced with Mongo then I currently am. Many thanks for your thoughts and help!

Comment: @Mattijs I would just like to see a clear question with a clear result as an answer. That helps others with similar problems. If the question is not clearly related to the results then it is confusing and not helpful as a resource. We do aim to help "you" here, but the primary focus is what is useful for everyone else. Hence everything I have said here.

Comment: Yes I understand. And that is the power of Stackoverflow which is very beneficial to me and also others. So Thanks again, I reckon there are enough parts in above examples that can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

I have come to sort a solution with the help of Blakes Seven answer.
The following query seems to work and is based on the start dataset posted in my first question. The addition is adding 2 groups at the end to create my desired result.

```
      db.reportData.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          'CIC package': 1,
          'Start Date': 1,
          'Status': 1
        }
      }, 
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$CIC package',
          package: {
            $first: '$CIC package'
          },
          status: {
            $push: '$Status'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$status'
      },
      {
        $group:
        {
          _id: 
          {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "package": "$package",
            "status": "$status"
          },
          package: {
            $first: '$package'
          },
          status: {
            $first: '$status'
          },
          count:{
            $sum: 1
          }

        }

      },
      {
        $group:
        {
          _id: "$_id._id",
          package: {
            $first: "$_id.package"
          },
          status:
          {
            $push:
            {
              "status" : "$_id.status",
              "count": '$count'

            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]).toArray()
```

It results in a dataset like this:

```
[
      {
        "_id" : "Studio Canal",
        "package" : "Studio Canal",
        "status" : [
          {
            "status" : "Completed",
            "count" : 8
          },
          {
            "status" : "Cancelled",
            "count" : 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id" : "Meeting / forum",
        "package" : "Meeting / forum",
        "status" : [
          {
            "status" : "Cancelled",
            "count" : 254
          },
          {
            "status" : "Completed",
            "count" : 275
          },
          {
            "status" : "Processing",
            "count" : 6
          },
          {
            "status" : "Tentative",
            "count" : 1
          },
          {
            "status" : "Confirmed",
            "count" : 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id" : "Design Thinking workshop",
        "package" : "Design Thinking workshop",
        "status" : [
          {
            "status" : "Cancelled",
            "count" : 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id" : "Test Gallery Café",
        "package" : "Test Gallery Café",
        "status" : [
          {
            "status" : "Cancelled",
            "count" : 1
          },
          {
            "status" : "Completed",
            "count" : 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id" : "Not specified",
        "package" : "Not specified",
        "status" : [
          {
            "status" : "Completed",
            "count" : 124
          },
          {
            "status" : "Tentative",
            "count" : 1
          },
          {
            "status" : "Cancelled",
            "count" : 42
          },
          {
            "status" : "Confirmed",
            "count" : 4
          },
          {
            "status" : "Processing",
            "count" : 5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id" : "Customer / partner / special event",
        "package" : "Customer / partner / special event",
        "status" : [
          {
            "status" : "Tentative",
            "count" : 1
          },
          {
            "status" : "Cancelled",
            "count" : 145
          },
          {
            "status" : "Processing",
            "count" : 3
          },
          {
            "status" : "Completed",
            "count" : 284
          },
          {
            "status" : "Confirmed",
            "count" : 8
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id" : "Product / solution demonstration",
        "package" : "Product / solution demonstration",
        "status" : [
          {
            "status" : "Tentative",
            "count" : 1
          },
          {
            "status" : "Confirmed",
            "count" : 4
          },
          {
            "status" : "Cancelled",
            "count" : 82
          },
          {
            "status" : "Completed",
            "count" : 130
          },
          {
            "status" : "Processing",
            "count" : 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

which is what I am looking for. I have to check now if the data is correct but it looks like it.
Only question now is can/should I optimise it. Maybe something for tomorrow.